# Magento2 Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page while creating configurable product

Tags: magento2, php, configurable-product

While creating the configuration products in **Magento2.2.2** I am facing the

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

error. I have google regarding this error and I have found the solution to

> Increase the value of max_input_vars PHP configurable variable

I have increased this value but the problem is not solved.

While creating the **configurable product** almost 40000 associated product is generated and now I have set the **`max_input_vars`** value to **`3075000`** but the problem is not solved.

Anyone, please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Then clear browser cache. Especially clear or delete cookies.

Comment: Try in private window

Comment: I have already tried this cache clear and private windows. Even I have tried from another computer but problem not solved.

Comment: try restarting the apache server and then check again

Comment: @surbhiagr I have tried with restart the apache & mysql also. But same problem.

Comment: try changing the base_url like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122167/78426

Comment: try with table core_config_data find path - 'web/cookie/cookie_domain' than remove row.

Comment: @rinzler I am trying this on server not on local machine.

Comment: @AnasMansuri already tried this.

Comment: @Narayan how specifically are you creating the associated simple products & associating to configurable? programmatically or via admin interface? Limiting the `input_vars` per chunk of association is prefered to avoid limits like this and memory, etc.

Comment: Narayan, did you manage to find a solution to your issue?

Comment: @Mammouth No not yet :)

Answer (score 1):

If Linux (Fedora)
go to

```
sudo vi /etc/php.ini
```

Change `memory_limit = 128M` to `2040M`

check `session.gc_maxlifetime` if its commented like

`";session.gc_maxlifetime"`

then change to

session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

after that restart your apache server

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below possibilities :

1 check with php info max_input_vars are updated or not. may be if you are using multiple php versions, so you assign value to another php.ini
also please verify below values :

2 check with your database table `core_config_data` find path=`web/cookie/cookie_domain`, if you find row than remove it.

I hope its work for you.

Comment: yes all the php configuration updated correctly. check the setting here https://i.imgur.com/6UB1vzE.png.

I have already tried this cookie setting before its empty (no records in Db) I have added a record and check again but its not working. then I have reverted by deleting the records

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved by changing the PHP settings.

```
max_input_vars = 100000
max_input_nesting_level = 800
max_input_time = 18000
```

Reference :[Php max_input_vars prevents attribute options saving in M2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215308/68695)

Then run command

**if Linux (Debian/Ubuntu):**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: max_input_vars & max_input_time I have already set this to maximum. But I don't think we have to increase the `max_input_nesting_level ` to 800. Now it is 64. Can you please tell me why should I increase this as I think 64 level is sufficient.

Comment: @Narayan you can contact your server team they are given you perfect number

Comment: Yes I will thanks!