# Product Page Bug Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, product, bug, form-key

I am making a product page that has a product with multiple options for height and width in a dropdown. When I more than about 40 options, the page wont save them anymore. The page will just say

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

I tried refreshing the page, clearing the browser cookies and cache, clearing magento cache and clearing values in web/cookie/cookie_domain and web/cookie/cookie_path in the core_config_data table. I've tried different browsers in incongnito mode and they all seem to fail once I try to add to many values. Here is my webpage with some of the values. https://buyglass.woodstove-fireplaceglass.com/pyroceramic-glass.html
Has anyone had this happen to them before, or have any other ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked max input vars https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/231208/70343

Comment: I just tried adding php_value max_input_vars 6000 to the bottom of .htaccess and it caused my site to crash

Comment: Okay so I added that code under <IfModule mod_php7.c> in the htaccess and there are no errors, but it does not look like the value changed in my phpinfo page

Comment: I added the rule max_input_vars = 6000 into the user.ini file and it worked! No more erros, thank you so much! If you add it as an answer I will choose it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked max input vars

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/231208/70343

I think what was happening was the submission wasn't catching all of the fields in the form submission. One of which was the form key.